# Saving local village over Google+ village

Tags: clash-of-clans, android

I am currently playing Clash of Clans on my Android phone and have gotten fairly far into the game. Far enough to where I would like to connect my village to my Google+ account.

The only problem is that my current Google+ account has a Clash of Clans village already loaded onto it with a Town Hall of level 1. Is there any way for me to get rid of my Clash of Clans village on my Google+ account in order to save my local village onto that account?

I have currently gone into my Google Settings and then into my Connected Apps and disconnected the Clash of Clans app while deleting all activities for that app as well. When I tried to connect to Google+ through Clash of Clans after that, it still prompted me to load my Town Hall level 1 village.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The link is done on the SuperCell servers, and there's no way to unlink an account from a Google+ (Android) or Game Center account (iOS).

You will need to create a new Google+ account to link to your village.

Just FYI, there's some information I found on Google that suggests you can unlink it by going into Google+ settings. I just tried these suggestions with a test village of mine and can co firm that process doesn't work.

Comment: I'd play it until reach TH 7 and forget to back up it. Still playing, any suggest? Hope my device will not broken someday...Haha...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove your old town hall from your Google account.

1. Open your Android device, of course.
2. Open Google Settings.
3. Open Connected Apps then tap to Clash of Clans.
4. Tap to Disconnect to remove this game from your account.
5. Done.

Comment: I tested this and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannnot I have tried and yes you can disconnect your game but when I reconnected my game to save my game it still tried to load my lvl 2 town hall saying it would delet my current game lvl 8 town hall.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this does not work. You can try to disconnect the game but it doesn't delete your game history it only deletes the sign in.

Answer (score 0):

OK..I found a solution....I was going through the same thing, here's what I did.

Phone I play on: Samsung Galaxy Note 1

1. Go on your phone or android device and open CoC and wait for it to load.
2. Go to settings in the bottom right corner.
3. I you are currently disconnected the skip, if you are connected then disconnect
   under settings by pressing Google+ Sign-In
4. Go to Google and create an account that you will use to back up CoC or any other game you 
   have on your device. (for example: yourname123backup@gmail.com)
5. Go into settings (the phones settings or your android device settings)
6. Go to accounts and click on the account that is currently backing CoC.
7. On the bottom of the screen select "Remove account"
   It will read "Removing the account will delete all of its messages, contacts, 
   and other data from the device. Continue? Select Remove account.
8. Go on your phone or android device and open CoC and wait for it to load.
9. Go to settings in the bottom right corner.
10. Under settings press Google+ Sign-In
11. Use the account information you created in step 1
12. Follow all on screen directions.
13. After your game is backed up go into settings (the phones settings or your 
    android device settings)
14. Go to accounts and select "add account"
15. Select Google and select existing.
16. Put in your previous account that was removed in step 4. (This account will be associated 
    with your previos apps except CoC
17. Make sure to sync you of your current accounts.

Good Luck!

Note: Your current village will now be associated with the new account in step 1.  The old village will still be associated with the old account.