# If I make a new Gmail account, will my CoC village be affected?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I forgot the password of my Gmail account. I want to make a new account, but I'm worried about losing my progress.

If I make a new account, will my Clash of Clans village be affected or lost?

Comment: and what can I do for my other problem that... my old village was lost while I'm still using the same account?

Comment: Other question: why don't you try to restore the password? What's the problem with that?

Comment: anyway thanks everyone because I already remembered my password.

Answer (score 1):

If your COC account is linked then it will start fresh. If not then it's local data and should be fine.

Comment: Can you please add some additional information to back this up?

Comment: its sort of realated to [link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189674/saving-local-village-over-google-village)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Linking your CoC account to Google+ or Facebook is used mainly for issues where you accidentally delete CoC, or any other time when it needs recovery. As long as you don't sign in with your new account, then it shouldn't mess it up.

For this particular situation, I would recommend going [here](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery). You can reset your password (unless you don't have another email), and keep playing normally. If you *don't* have another email account, you should either back it up using Facebook or start a new CoC account.

Hope this helps!